# Magento 2: Change DB Name Without affecting core files

Tags: magento2, database

I'm running custom script on my Linux Server.

I don't want that script to affect my current database. Username/Password/Host will be same.

Only DB name is changed. How can I do that without changing in `env.php`?

```
// MAGENTO START
include(dirname(__DIR__) . '/app/bootstrap.php');

use Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap;

$bootstrap = Bootstrap::create(BP, $_SERVER);
$objectManager = $bootstrap->getObjectManager();

$state = $objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\App\State');
$state->setAreaCode('frontend');
$deploymentConfig = $objectManager->create('Magento\Framework\App\DeploymentConfig');
$dbName = $deploymentConfig->get('db/connection/default/dbname'); // Get Current DB Name
```

On server my website is already running. Don't want to affect that. So need to run script for new DB only.

Comment: Did you find out how to change the DB name?

Answer (score 0):

In Magento, change the name of the database in `app/etc/env.php` and rename your mysql database this way:

```
mysqldump old_database > database_content.out
mysql -e "CREATE DATABASE new_database CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci;"
mysql new_database < database_content.out 
mysql -e "DROP DATABASE old_database;"
```